# Prevent horizontal "scrolling" of a text input?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input

I am working on a format input field in html, css and js.

One example would be a date format field with following pattern: `**.**.****`. When I am typing in the input fields, Chrome "scrolls" to the left when I reach the end of the box.

How can I prevent this?

[image]

The lines that separate each char are made by a background image. With a monospaced font and a set `letter-spacing` each character goes into a "field". If you reach the size of the input field it scrolls forward and takes the background with it.

To resolve this problem, I put the input element into a div element, limited the div element to a width and added borders and `overflow: none;` to the div. The result: It works fine in Firefox, Chrome still scrolls the input content to the left.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there an other solution for that? Is there a -webkit property to prevent this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found a CSS solution:

```css
  #input-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #C9CFD5;
    background-image: url('grid.png'); /* some tile image for the vertical lines */
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #input-wrapper input {
    border: 0 none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Courier", monospace;
    letter-spacing: 28px;
    text-indent: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" maxlength="4" length="4" value="1234" />
</div>
```

Have fun!

Comment: Doesn't look like this works anymore in the latest chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/Vm3ye/

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the advise with the wrapper, I had the same problem in firefox.
In Chrome I fixed it using JS and the scrollLeft method (which will not work in ff on the other hand).
In jQuery:

```
$('input').live('keyup', function() {
    $(this).parent().scrollLeft(0);
});
```

Comment: this is fine in both Chrome and FireFox, but unfortunately, `scrollLeft` works in IE only on elements having scrollbars (check the MSDN docs for `scrollLeft`), so in case of `input`, there are no scrollbars and `scrollLeft` does not work :(

Comment: I solved it now by hiding the original input with `opacity: 0` and showing the input value in a helper element (`pointer-events: none` is very useful here!). You just have to update this mirrored value with a change event listener. As I'm using angular this was very easy through to two way data binding.

Answer (score 0):

i used the following solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="input-wrapper">
    <div id="input-grid">
    <input type="text" id="targa" maxlength="5" length="5" value="" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#targa').on('keypress', function() {
    if (this.value.length >= 4){
        return false;
    }  
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
  #input-wrapper {
      position: relative;
  }
  #input-grid{
    border: 1px solid #C9CFD5;
    background-image: url('../images/input-mask.jpg'); 
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  #targa {
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border: 0 none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Courier", monospace;
    letter-spacing: 28px;
    text-indent: 18px;
    outline: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

[jsfiddle live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm3ye/4/)

[jsfiddle live example (full screen)](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm3ye/4/embedded/result/)

Comment: Hi, I was using your method to do this, until I did around ten spaces and the letters got off. can you help me fix this http://jsfiddle.net/Vm3ye/12/

Comment: you need modify CSS.
Change the width value to 500px on #targa.

Answer (score -1):

Webkit goes head over heels to show you what you are typing, even if you do css transformations it won't hide the text input caret.

It is also bad user experience to hide what you're typing, it would be very disconcerting and you wouldn't know if you typed it right.

I would suggest to limit the amount of characters you can put into each field, such as...

```
<input type="text" maxlength="20" />
```

If your really need an arbitrary amount of characters, then you could listen for the keyup event on the field and then grow it dynamically.

Comment: I was planning to use javascript to jump into the second field. When I limit the size, the same effect take place, because of the letter-space, he jumps into the next field outside the input element.

Comment: Sorry, I meant maxlength, not size. If you use maxlength does it still happen?

Comment: Maxlength limits the char count but it moves the cursor to the end of the field. (like you see in the picture above) Same effect..