# Disable scroll in input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, scroll

I've got an input field with a background image to separate the letters in boxes.

The problem appear when I reach the end of the input: the input view scrolls down due to the cursor position placed after the last letter.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qy1w.png)

How can I avoid the view to scroll in my inputs?

I've tried to add an "`overflow:hidden`" and to set a "`maxlength`", the problem is still there.

edit: [a simple demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/n23dfs4t/) (My goal is to avoid the "move effect" when the 4th letter is entered)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent horizontal "scrolling" of a text input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961045/prevent-horizontal-scrolling-of-a-text-input)

Comment: Share you working/attempted code.! Let us what have done so far. this is not a proper way to ask question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @NestorLeCastor Please add a portion of you html code buddy... so that we can guide you better...

Comment: Please write your Html and Css code so I will suggest you your answer.

Comment: You could just make the `input` slightly wider so that there's space for the carat after the fourth character: https://jsfiddle.net/n23dfs4t/1/

Comment: Please insert code for a better understanding.

Comment: Here's a Chromium bug on the subject https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 solutions :

## CSS solution

Like said in comment, you could slightly increase the with of your input to prevent this 'jump' behavior
like : `width : 202px`

[fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/u0e1zLku/)

## JavaScript solution

If you can't/ don't want to change the width of your input you can prevent the keypress event, then check the length of the input value. If it less than 4 add it else do nothing.

#### Jquery way:

```
var t = $('#input-form');
t.keypress( function(event){
    //Prevent the value to be added
    event.preventDefault();
    //Regex that you can change for whatever you allow in the input (here any word character --> alphanumeric & underscore)
    var reg = /\w/g;
    //retreive the key pressed
    var inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    //retreive the input's value length
    var inputLength = t.val().length;

    if ( reg.test(inputChar) && (inputLength < 4) ) {
        //if input length < 4, add the value
        t.val(t.val() + inputChar);
    }else{
        //else do nothing
        return;
    }
});
```

[fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/dLbr0n65/1/)

#### Pure JavaScript:

```
var t = document.getElementById('input-form');

t.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
    //Prevent the value to be added
    event.preventDefault();
    //Regex that you can change for whatever you allow in the input (here any word character --> alphanumeric & underscore)
    var reg = /\w/g;
    //retreive the input's value length
    var inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    //retreive the input's value length
    var inputLength = t.value.length;
    if ( reg.test(inputChar) && (inputLength < 4) ) {
        //if input length < 4, add the value
        t.value = t.value + inputChar;
    }else{
        //else do nothing
        return;
    }
});
```

[fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/nf88es7d/)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a small alteration to your field width in your CSS code, see below:

```
input {
width: 205px;
height: 50px;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: "Courier", monospace;
letter-spacing: 28px;
text-indent: 18px;
position: fixed;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Try typing something now and keep an eye on the fourth character.

Hope this helps.

Sohail.