# How to style the last char from input text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-content

I have the following snippet which `styles` one input text element as follows:

Every written `char` will be placed into a special square box. The **problem** is that appeared a strange behaviour when I wrote the last char(when `maxlength` property is reached). The text is just moved some pixels to the left.

That behaviour can be observed here:

```css
#text{
    background-image: url("https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/29/03/20/1656fa8074e9571.jpg");
    width: 255px;
    height: 18px;
    background-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 13px;
}
```

```html
<br>Cnp: <input type="text" maxlength="13" id="text"/> </br>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent horizontal "scrolling" of a text input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961045/prevent-horizontal-scrolling-of-a-text-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `letter-spacing` is just too wide. Try changing it to:

```
letter-spacing: 12.3px;
```

I arrived at the number `12.3` by just testing it in the browser.

Comment: This way every character will placed more and more closer to the starting line of its box.

Comment: This actually looks perfect in the browser

Comment: If this is the perfect solution for you then okay, I just leave it here: https://i.imgur.com/QJGOC9a.png

Comment: That's not what it looks like at all

Comment: I just tried it here on the snippet editor, and on another sites as well. But just do the math, a 12.3px wide character will exactly fit a 13px wide block? I'm not so sure...

Comment: I also did it in the snippet editor and it looked perfect

Comment: Maybe on your device, on your browser, it works... But i'm sure it looks different in every single browser, and in most of it, it looks like on my screenshot (or worse).

Comment: @BalázsVarga, your solution is good, but I need a solution without javascript.

Comment: Then you will struggle so much to get it work in every browser, prepare for browser specific media queries and a lot of headaches. Good luck!

Comment: @BalázsVarga what browser are you using

Comment: @rpivovar Chrome

Comment: weird, so am I and it looks great

Comment: works great in firefox, too (I don't see why it wouldn't)

Comment: Why not using a monospace font ?

Comment: @BalázsVarga I'm upvoting your solution though

Comment: I tested it in more browsers but things started to get more weird, especially with IE (where it appends an [X] to the input). I think (like @Kangouroops suggested) using a monospace font with the right font-size is the only one acceptabe pure css solution.

Comment: @BalázsVarga you're right - my answer is a very simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

That's beacuse your letters are "wider" than they really are, because of letter spacing. To get rid of this (default) behaviour, you need to add a little bit of javascript to reset the elements `scrollLeft` to `0` after insertion.

Now I just added these handlers via html `onkeyup` and `onchange`, as you can see it works.

```css
#text{
    background-image: url("https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/29/03/20/1656fa8074e9571.jpg");
    width: 255px;
    height: 18px;
    background-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 13px;
}
```

```html
<br>Cnp: <input type="text" maxlength="13" id="text" onkeyup="this.scrollLeft = 0;" onchange="this.scrollLeft = 0;" /> </br>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..can you provide a solution with only css ?

Comment: Maybe it's possible, but you can't do it without nasty css hacks.